# Can't downgrade libboost-iostreams-dev 1.58 to 1.55

Tags: 15.10, downgrade

I am trying to install python-graph-tools on my Ubuntu 15.10 but it says that

```
    python-graph-tool : Depends: libboost-iostreams1.55.0 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libboost-python1.55.0 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libboost-regex1.55.0 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libcairomm-1.0-1 (>= 1.6.4) but it is not installable
                 Depends: python-scipy but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libboost-graph1.55.0 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libboost-system1.55.0 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libboost-thread1.55.0 but it is not installable
                 Depends: python-matplotlib but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcgal10 but it is not installable
      E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

While I have libboost-iostream 1.58 on my PC. I also tried removing this package using

```
       sudo sudo apt-get --purge remove libboost-iostreams
```

And  tried to install libboost iostream 1.55 using the code

```
       sudo apt-get install libboost-iostreams-dev 1.55
```

but it again installs the 1.58 version.

Comment: The cause here is not libboost-iostream1.55.0, but one of the packages mentioned as dependencies.  One or more in that list cannot be installed, for reasons we don't know. 
You might also have a broken repository.  Try `apt-get -f install` to fix eventual corruptions.   If it still doesn't install, try installing each of the mentioned packages manually to see why they refuse to install.

Comment: EOL release won't break repository actually. It'll work though won't get newer updates. The #1 culprit  for these cases is PPA. However, since 15.10 is EOL, we'll close it