# python3-graph-tool / gtk+3 installation error 'Depends: libboost-iostreams1.55.0 but it is not installable...'

Tags: python3, gtk3

I had so far imagined that on ubuntu this would be done in one shot, but well well well..

These issues - I had expected a good internet connection would resolve - are still blocking clean install of graph-tool on pyhon3.6, Ubuntu18 on my MSI.

It could be due to my using the [outdated installation instruction](https://gist.github.com/nlap/56061e47a2a8d69eb5f3), even though I tried to make sure I used libraries suitable for python3 not 2:

*what I actaully did, but not necessarily in the order as either the connection was problematic or I recognized what I installed was not in sync with version 3.6*

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install expat
sudo apt-get -y install libsparsehash-dev
sudo apt-get -y install gtk+3
```

*gtk+3 was the issue - and it has been on Mac OS as well

```
sudo apt-get -y install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pygraphviz
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential
sudo apt-get -y install libcairo2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
sudo apt-get -y install python3-dev
sudo apt-get -y install python3-matplotlib
sudo apt-get -y install gfortran libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libcgal-dev
sudo apt-get -y install python3-numpy (did pip install)
sudo apt-get -y install python2.7-config
```

(not quite working with python3.6m-config but it shows when I type `whereis python`)

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-cairo
sudo apt-get -y install python3-scipy (did pip install)
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.skewed.de --recv-key 98507F25
echo 'deb http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/trusty trusty universe' | sudo tee -a  /etc/apt/sources.list
echo 'deb-src http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/trusty trusty universe' | sudo tee -a  /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install python3-graph-tool
```

So the following are the error messages:

```
Depends: libboost-iostreams1.55.0 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-python1.55.0 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-regex1.55.0 but it is not installable
Depends: libcairomm-1.0-1 (1>= 1.6.4) but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-graph1.55.0 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-system1.55.0 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-thread1.55.0 but it is not installable
Depends: libcgal10 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

While I understand that these indicate not really the 'broken packages' but in fact regard the dependencies on past versions of certain packages - after a number of searches on similar issues - I still haven't quite resolved this. Even worse, I dont see why `libboost-python1.55.0` should even be used for python3-graph-tool

The [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816119/cant-downgrade-libboost-iostreams-dev-1-58-to-1-55) and a lot of others suggested `apt-get -f install` but it returned nothing, every time.

I had suspicion that the fact `unity-gtk3-module` conflicts with `appmenu-gtk3` could be a problem - but it stopped returning in output on terminal at some point.

Comment: The major outdated thing in the instructions that sticks out is the use of **trusty** repositories (`echo 'deb http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/trusty trusty universe'`)

Comment: I did correct it to `xenial`, but as the problem persists, by now I'm sure my using multiple terminal tabs at a slow connection (while on the move) had messed up the dependencies. How do I undo everything I already installed now.. hahaha.